# Продувная бестия

Tags: фразеология

Есть такое выражение - "продувная бестия". Собственно, с бестией все понятно. Хотя изначально это слово и не было ругательным. Но вот интересно, почему она именно продувная? Честно говоря, у меня даже версий никаких нет.

Answer (score 1):

Как известно, воздух способен проникать даже в самые труднодоступные места. А поскольку продувной бестией обычно называют хитрого, находчивого человека, то тем самым подчеркивается его способность с легкостью проникать (продувать все щели, отверстия и лазы) всюду, подобно воздуху.